# Exception during live image creation

Tags: java, eclipse

When I create a JLabel, it has a error like the following image.
I see error like that:
"WindowBuilder encountered unexpected internal error. 
This could be caused by a WindowBuilder bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partial update, etc.
java.lang.Error: new JLabel("New label") "
How I can repair it.
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the error log like it suggests?  What error(s) do you see there?

Comment: WindowBuilder encountered unexpected internal error. 

This could be caused by a WindowBuilder bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partial update, etc.

java.lang.Error: new JLabel("New label")

Comment: I see it, but I'm newbie and I don't know any about it

Comment: Please don't post comments to expand on your question.  Instead, edit the original question to add more information.  Also, it's important to include the *complete* text of any errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because the windows builder plugin downloaded from eclipse repository is not compatible with the eclipse version.
This issue generally comes in lower version of eclipse like indigo.

Try following URL:
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201406251200/4.4/

With Eclipse Kepler. Works like charm.